# iOS Twitter and Facebook sign on for a third party web service

Tags: ios, facebook, web-services, authentication, twitter

This is the experience I want for my users:

- Open app
- Sign in with facebook or twitter
- Communicate with my web service in a secure fashion

I would like to use the native sign in to these services (Facebook and twitter) in iOS, but I want all communication with my web service to be secure and authenticated.

At the moment I can do a iOS native sign on which authenticates the user. I then know that the user is signed in and I can query the authentication providers for information about the user. What this does not give me is a way to then communicate with my web service and know that the person communicating with the web service is an authenticated user.

Or I can implement the sign on in my web service (or use something like [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) to deal with it). Then I can definitely know that the user is authenticated but then I miss the nice native experience of signing in.

Is there a hybrid approach where the user can sign in using the native iOS controls and I can use that authentication information to form secure access to my web service?

Comment: Got to love it when people downvote your question without leaving a reason

Comment: This question should be reopened

Answer (score 3):

> What this does not give me is a way to then communicate with my web service and know that the person communicating with the web
>   service is an authenticated user.

Yes it does. Lets say they login with facebook. Great, we now have an `access_token`. Pass that `access_token` to a web service on your server. Have the script contact the Graph API to get their `uid` for that `access_token`. Match that `uid` against your database of connected accounts. And bam! You now know what user you're dealing with.

From there, set cookies and such so that you don't have to repeat the `uid` lookup each time.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, so would the process be: On initial sign in the user authenticates and receives the access_token, then lets say I make them create a profile and when I transmit that data to the service I attach the access_token. At the server I contact the facebook server and get the uid, create the user account and store the uid along with that account. Then on subsequent requests I have that uid stored. Every request will have an attached access_token.

Comment: Correct. Attaching an `access_token` with each request will be inefficient b/c you're calling an external api each time you do that. But you could even cache the results in a database table with a `access_token` and `fb_uid` and `my_system_user_id` to speed things up